# Is there any way to focus the mechanical vibration or stress of an object?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am looking for a way to focus the vibration of a metal sheet at a specific point on that sheet so that other points vibrate less. Just like light and lens. Is there any way to focus the mechanical vibration or stress of an object?

Comment: add masses at the nodes.

Comment: hi zeynab welcome to Engineering. Can you share a bit more information? How is the vibration applied on the sheet? What can you tell us about its supports? Is the excitation frequency constant or does it vary quite a lot?